# Run a function from bashrc, but modify exported variable

Tags: bash, environment-variables

I am trying to run a function from my bashrc that refreshes every minute and externalizes a variable. It looks like this:

```
export CFN = ''
_some_fn
{
    export CFN = 'test'
    sleep 60
    _some_fn &
}
_some_fn &
```

Where 'test' is variable, but when I source this, I have no access to the CFN from inside the function, which I suspect is due to the fact that it is running in subshell. Is there a way to change the value of CFN that was exported?

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible with your current function, as soon as you background it with `&` it takes a copy of the process stack and leaves. There is no way for the changes to your stack to propagate to the job's copy unless you explicitly build that functionality, and it's similarly impossible to get changes to the function's stack into your current stack.

You could set up some interprocess communication to change the variable, but that's always quite tricky to get right, and I'm not sure what your use case is. Example of IPC both ways:

```
mkfifo -m 600 /var/tmp/cfn-to-fn
mkfifo -m 600 /var/tmp/cfn-from-fn
export CFN = ''
_some_fn
{
     read CFN < /var/tmp/cfn-to-fn
     # do something with the new CFN here
     echo 'processed data' >/var/tmp/cfn-from-fn
     _some_fn &
}
_some_fn &
echo 'processme' > /var/tmp/cfn-to-fn
cat /var/tmp/cfn-from-fn
```

There are many alternatives to mkfifo, generally all spoken of under the tag of [Inter-process communication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication#Implementations). If you find virtue in keeping things simple, don't bother with these and just write you data to a file on one end and read it on the other. D-Bus is the big IPC bus on most unix systems, along with TCP/ or UDP/IP (with `netcat` or `nc` ) but I haven't seen much shell scripts that use those.

Your final alternative is to leave all this for what it is and get your script to work without running it as a background job so that you can tweak the environment as it runs.

Comment: Is there an alternative you can think of that I should explore to achieve the same end?